# Get WebBrowser Control to Check Radio Option

Tags: vb6

I want my vb6 program to check radio option and submit it through a PHP page. I have the following code:

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_DocumentComplete(ByVal pDisp As Object, URL As Variant)
   If WebBrowser1.LocationURL = "http://xx.xxxxxxxxxx.com/vb6.php" Then
      WebBrowser1.Document.frmC.cid.Value = "52821558"
      WebBrowser1.Document.frmC.instrument.Value = "CL"
      'WebBrowser1.Document.frmC.ctype
      WebBrowser1.Document.frmC.Submit.Click
   End If
End Sub
```

`"ctype"` in the code above represents the name of the radio option and bellow its HTML code

```
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="ctype" value="Buy"><span style="font-size: 14px">Buy</span>
<INPUT TYPE="Radio" Name="ctype" value="Sell"><span style="font-size: 14px">Sell</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SetAttribute`:

```
Dim radio As Object
Set radio = WebBrowser1.Document.frmC.ctype.Item(0)
radio.SetAttribute "checked", "checked"
```

Use `.Item(0)` for the first radio & `.Item(1)` for the second.